# Recreating bar chart with R and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, recreate

Heyy, can anyone help with recreating a graph in R using ggplot2?

```
library(ggplot)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)
```

We were thinking of creating two separate graphs and combining them using patchwork or cowplot and also ggthemes for the design. Would be great if anyone with some more experience could help us with how to approach this task. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, @DataVizBizz--lots of people here will be willing to help. But you're far more likely to get the help you seek if you follow SO custom and post (1) your data or at least a `dput()` thereof and (2) whatever code you've worked with so far. Cheers!

Comment: Heyy @RKeithL thanks for your your feedback, we'll try to improve the post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just out of curiosity and as an exercise, here is a possible approach to recreate the original FiveThirtyEight chart based on `facet_grid` and many additional customizations for the right look and all the details.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)

data <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/masculinity-survey/raw-responses.csv", col_names = TRUE) %>%
  select(q0005, age3)

table(data$q0005)

pal_color <- c("#ED713A", "#8DDADF", "#CDCDCD")
names(pal_color) <- c("Yes", "No", "No answer")

pal_fte <- deframe(ggthemes::ggthemes_data[["fivethirtyeight"]])

data_sum <- data |>
  count(q0005, age3) |>
  mutate(group = "b")

data_sum <- data_sum |>
  summarise(
    group = "a",
    age3 = "All adult men",
    n = sum(n),
    .by = q0005
  ) |>
  bind_rows(data_sum) |>
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n), .by = age3) |>
  mutate(
    age3 = case_match(
      age3,
      "18 - 34" ~ "18-34",
      "35 - 64" ~ "35-64",
      "65 and up" ~ "65+",
      .default = age3
    ),
    age3 = factor(
      age3,
      rev(c("18-34", "35-64", "65+", "All adult men"))
    ),
    q0005 = factor(
      q0005,
      rev(c("Yes", "No answer", "No"))
    )
  )

data_labels <- data_sum |>
  filter(group == "a") |>
  arrange(desc(q0005)) |>
  mutate(
    pct = cumsum(pct),
    pctlag = lag(pct, default = 0),
    y = .5 * pct + .5 * pctlag
  )

data_segment <- data_labels |>
  filter(q0005 == "No answer")
data_labels <- data_labels |> 
  filter(q0005 != "No answer")

ggplot(data_sum, aes(pct, age3)) +
  geom_segment(
    data = data_segment,
    aes(
      x = .4, xend = y,
    ),
    y = 0, yend = 0, color = pal_fte[["Dark Gray"]]
  ) +
  geom_segment(
    data = data_segment,
    aes(
      x = y, xend = y,
    ),
    y = 0, yend = 1, color = pal_fte[["Dark Gray"]]
  ) +
  geom_label(
    data = data.frame(
      x = .4, group = "a", hjust = 0,
      label = "No answer"
    ),
    aes(x = x, hjust = hjust, label = label),
    y = 0, hjust = 0, color = pal_fte[["Dark Gray"]],
    label.size = 0, fill = pal_fte[["Light Gray"]],
    inherit.aes = FALSE, size = .8 * 12 / .pt
  ) +
  geom_vline(
    xintercept = .5
  ) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = q0005), width = .6) +
  geom_vline(
    xintercept = c(0, 1)
  ) +
  geom_label(
    data = data_labels,
    aes(x = pctlag, label = q0005),
    hjust = 0, nudge_x = .025,
    fontface = "bold", label.size = 0, fill = NA,
    size = .8 * 12 / .pt
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(x = -.25, hjust = 0, label = age3),
    fontface = "bold", size = .8 * 12 / .pt
  ) +
  geom_text(
    data = data.frame(
      group = "b"
    ),
    aes(x = -.25, hjust = 0, label = "BY AGE GROUP"),
    y = 4, color = "black",
    size = .6 * 12 / .pt
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = pal_color,
    guide = "none"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = seq(0, 1, .1),
    labels = \(x) paste0(100 * x, c("%", rep("", 10))),
    position = "top",
    expand = c(0, 0)
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  facet_grid(group ~ ., space = "free_y", scales = "free_y") +
  ggthemes::theme_fivethirtyeight(base_size = 12) +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    strip.text.y = element_blank(),
    panel.spacing.y = unit(1, "cm"),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      family = "mono",
      color = pal_fte[["Dark Gray"]]
    ),
    plot.title.position = "plot",
    plot.title = element_text(
      size = rel(1.25)
    ),
    plot.caption = element_text(
      family = "mono",
      size = rel(.6),
      color = pal_fte[["Dark Gray"]],
      margin = margin(20, unit = "pt")
    ),
    plot.caption.position = "plot"
  ) +
  labs(
    x = NULL, y = NULL,
    title = paste(
      "Do you think society puts pressure on men in a way",
      "that is unhealthy or bad for them?",
      sep = "\n"
    ),
    subtitle = "",
    caption = "SOURCE: FIVETHIRTYEIGHT/DEATH, SEX & MONEY/SURVEY"
  )

ggsave("fivethirtyeight.png",
  width = 550, height = 350, units = "px",
  dpi = 300, scale = 300 / 96
)
```

[image]